# PHP preg_match with or without letters in front?

Tags: php

Hi I currently have this:

```
$linkOcc = substr_count($text3, "**link(");
        if($linkOcc < '1'){
            $text4 = $text3;

        }


        for ($i2=0; $i2 < $linkOcc; $i2++) { 
            if($i2=='0'){
                preg_match('/(?<=\*\*link)\((.*)\)/', $text3, $match2);
                $linkTitle = ($match2[1]);
                $linkTitle = str_replace("/","",$linkTitle);
            }
        }
```

It detects if there is a piece of text in a paragraph that macthes the following:

```
**link(exampletext)**
```

It then replaces it with something else. This works great if  there is a space(s) on both sides of the

```
**link(examplesite)**
```

But let's say I have the following paragraph:

```
So then Bob went to this**link(examplesite)**and he found a cool picture.
```

Then for some reason the code dosnt recognise it as then **link... I am fairly sure it's because there are no spaces on both sides of the **link... So how can I fix this? To detect **link... with AND without spaces on the side of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you only want to match the text between the parenthesis:

```
**link(this text)**
```

Then your regular expression needs to be be:

```
\*\*link\((.*)\)\*\*
```

You are just simply capturing any text -> (.*)
Inside the parenthesis -> \(  \)

To test the regular expression you can go here:
https://regex101.com/ and test it with or without spaces after or before **link(some text)**

IMPORTANT NOTE:
Since you only have one capturing group, the match is going to be on the first element of the match array: matches[0]

In your case if you want the matched content, you need to use $match2[0] instead of $match2[1]

Comment: I'm sorry but this wasnt the problem. I want to get the whole of **link(text)** with the *'s and the link part aswell the problem is that when I have text in front of the ** it does the whole of **link(text)** is not captured. But when there is spaces before the ** in  **link(text)** it does not get captured.

Comment: if you need to capture  the whole thing **\*\*link(this text)\*\*** (\*\*link\((.*)\)\*\*)

Comment: if you want to capture the whole thing then add a capturing group, like this: (\*\*link\((.*)\)\*\*)  

so the whole thing woild be matched[0] and the text between the parenthesis would be matched[1]